# Snake Game Loses Automatically

Tags: python, pygame

Basically the title. I'm not sure what the problem is. I have tried a couple little things to attempt to fix it. Copy and paste and wait a second before pressing any keys. It automatically loses. Would appreciate the help. Might be cause by my the wait I tried to add but I am not really sure. Should be a fairly quick fix. This is the last thing to do before my game is at least functional.

```
import pygame
import random

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
lime = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
Aqua = (0,255,255)

display_height = 800
display_width = 600


snake_width = 10
snake_length = 10
snake_x = 400
snake_y = 300

f = 0

food_w = 10
food_h = 10

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_height,display_width))

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def message_to_screen(msg, color, msgx, msgy):

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 18)
datext = font.render(msg, 1, color)
gameDisplay.blit(datext, [msgx, msgy])

def wait():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == 
                                                   pygame.K_RETURN:
                game()

def food(food_x,food_y):

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, [food_x, food_y, food_w, food_h])
    pygame.display.update()

def snake(block_size, snakelist):

    for XnY in snakelist:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, Aqua, [XnY[0], XnY[1], snake_width, 
snake_length])
    pygame.display.update()

def text_objects(text,font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def display_message(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 35)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((400),(300))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()

def score(count):
    myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 18)
    score_label = myFont.render("You're Score:" +str(count), 1, red)
    gameDisplay.blit(score_label, (0, 0))

def lose():

    display_message('You Lose! Press ENTER to Play Again')
    wait()
    game()

def game():



    food_startx = round(random.randrange(0, display_width-food_w)/10.0)*10.0
    food_starty = round(random.randrange(0, display_height-
                                         food_h)/10.0)*10.0

    snakelist = []
    snakeLength = 50

    f = 0


    snake_startx = 400
    snake_starty = 300
    snake_speedx = 0
    snake_speedy = 0
    block_size = (10,10)
    snake_head = (snake_startx, snake_starty)



    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    snake_speedx = -5
                    snake_speedy = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    snake_speedx = 5
                    snake_speedy = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    snake_speedy = -5
                    snake_speedx = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    snake_speedy = 5
                    snake_speedx = 0


        if snake_startx < 0 or snake_startx > 800 or snake_starty > 600 or 
                                                         snake_starty < 0:
            lose()

        score(f)
        snake_startx += snake_speedx
        snake_starty += snake_speedy


        snakeHead = []
        snakeHead.append(snake_startx)
        snakeHead.append(snake_starty)
        snakelist.append(snakeHead)

        if len(snakelist) > snakeLength and snakeHead!= 1:
            del snakelist[0]

            for eachSegment in snakelist[:-1]:
                if eachSegment == snakeHead and snakeHead != 1:
                    lose()

        snake(block_size, snakelist)
        food(food_startx, food_starty)

        if snake_startx == food_startx and snake_starty == food_starty:
            food_startx = round(random.randrange(0, display_width - food_w) 
                                                           / 10.0) * 10.0
            food_starty = round(random.randrange(0, display_height - food_h) 
                                                            / 10.0) * 10.0
            f += 1
            snakeLength += 1

        if food_startx >= 800 or food_startx <= 0:
            food_startx = round(random.randrange(0, display_width - food_w) 
/ 10.0) * 10.0
            food_starty = round(random.randrange(0, display_height - food_h) 
/ 10.0) * 10.0

        if food_starty >= 600 or food_starty <= 0:
            food_startx = round(random.randrange(0, display_width - food_w) 
/ 10.0) * 10.0
            food_starty = round(random.randrange(0, display_height - food_h) 
/ 10.0) * 10.0



        pygame.display.update()
        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        clock.tick(45)




game()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Presumably the three lines after `def message_to_screen` should be indented, right?

Comment: You can simplify conditions like `if x < 0 or x > y` to `if not 0 <= x <= y`.

Comment: yeah for some reason my pc has problems with putting the code in the correct format for the website so I have to go through and try my best to indent everything correctly. There are prob some more mistakes like this that aren't in the actual code

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were having was that you'd intialised your speed to `(0, 0)`, so the next generated segment was on top of itself, causing an immediate failure. I fixed this in addition to some other bugs, such as that your snake was moving out of phase of its length, whichc meant the snake could miss the food by half a block-length, so it would half-pass through the food. I've also tidied up your naming and added some neater idioms here and there (such as the chained comparator range-checking as suggested in the comments).

```
import pygame
import random

directions = {pygame.K_LEFT: (-1, 0),
              pygame.K_RIGHT: (1, 0),
              pygame.K_UP: (0, -1),
              pygame.K_DOWN: (0, 1),
              }

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
lime = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
aqua = (0,255,255)

display_width = 600
display_height = 800

snake_width = 10
snake_length = 10
snake_x = 400
snake_y = 300

food_w = 10
food_h = 10

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_height,display_width))

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def round_to_nearest(num, interval):
    return round(float(num) / interval) * interval

def rounded_in_range(start, stop, interval):
    return round_to_nearest(random.randrange(start, stop), interval)

def message_to_screen(msg, color, msgx, msgy):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 18)
    datext = font.render(msg, 1, color)
    game_display.blit(datext, [msgx, msgy])

def wait():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                game()

def food(food_x,food_y):
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, white, [food_x, food_y, food_w, food_h])
    pygame.display.update()

def snake(snake_width, snake_length, snake_segments):
    for XnY in snake_segments:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, aqua, [XnY[0], XnY[1], snake_width, snake_length])
    pygame.display.update()

def text_objects(text,font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def display_message(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 35)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = (400,300)
    game_display.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()

def score(count):
    myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 18)
    score_label = myFont.render("Your Score: {}".format(count), 1, red)
    game_display.blit(score_label, (0, 0))

def lose():
    display_message('You Lose! Press ENTER to Play Again')
    wait()
    game()

def game():
    food_x = rounded_in_range(food_w, display_width - food_w, food_w)
    food_y = rounded_in_range(food_h, display_height - food_h, food_h)

    snake_segments = []
    target_segments = 50

    player_score = 0

    snake_x = 400
    snake_y = 300
    snake_speedx, snake_speedy = directions[pygame.K_RIGHT]
    snake_speedx *= snake_width
    snake_speedy *= snake_length
    snake_head = (snake_x, snake_y)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                snake_speedx, snake_speedy = directions[event.key]
                snake_speedx *= snake_width
                snake_speedy *= snake_length

        if not 0 < snake_x < game_display.get_width() or not 0 < snake_y < game_display.get_height():
            lose()

        score(player_score)
        snake_x += snake_speedx
        snake_y += snake_speedy

        if len(snake_segments) > target_segments:
            del snake_segments[0]

        snake_head = [snake_x, snake_y]
        snake_segments.append(snake_head)

        for segment in snake_segments[:-1]:
            if segment == snake_head:
                lose()

        snake(snake_width, snake_length, snake_segments)
        food(food_x, food_y)

        if snake_x == food_x and snake_y == food_y:
            food_x = rounded_in_range(food_w, display_width - food_w, food_w)
            food_y = rounded_in_range(food_h, display_height - food_h, food_h)
            print("new food at {} {}".format(food_x, food_y))
            player_score += 1
            target_segments += 1

        pygame.display.update()
        game_display.fill(black)
        clock.tick(10)

game()
pygame.quit()
```

I'm not guaranteeing that this program is perfect - for example you can still turn back into yourself, causing immediate death, and food can spawn inside the body of the snake, but it should be operational now.

Comment: Really appreciate this. Me being new to this, I can't tell where you fixed the code to make sure the snake never missed the food by half a block. Can you point this out?

Comment: @EthanWilkes  No worries! In your code, your speed possibilities all had `5` - `(0, 5)` etc. Instead of this I just stored that as `(0, 1)`, and then later did `snake_speedx *= snake_width` so it always moves a full block length.